# "Accept" reputation events should be grouped with other events on the same post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, reputation-history

I have three reputation events on one post:

- Up vote (+5)
- Down vote (-2)
- Accepted answer (+2)

But the header text shows three events instead of grouping all three events.

[image: Screenshot of reputation list showing vote and accept events]

Also the count is showing +5/-2, without the points from the accept answer. I think it could be better if the text showed +7/-2  which means (+5 +2/-2 = upvote + accept / - downvote).

Comment: [Identical request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164062/295232) on Meta.SE

Comment: @Glorfindel good to know it's been a bug for close to 5 years

Comment: @Glorfindel Yup.

Comment: @George ! Am not sure it is a bug or feature request. But that  `@Tim Stone`  request is still pending with developers. That and it should be consider at this time. Weill See

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'd say a bug, as it does sometimes group them correctly

Comment: @George Shall I edit my question tag from feature request to bug?

Comment: @RameshRajendran That's down to you :)

Comment: @George Then leave it as of now :P

Answer (score 4):

It's apparently [not a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304875/238126), because the event is attached to the answer rather than the question itself. Seeing as it's [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), I think this is the intended behavior.

Comment: Intended behavior = [tag:status-bydesign]